# Shadow DOM not showing in DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

Following is code to mount shadow dom:

```
const template = makeTemplate() //helper function for styling etc
const host = document.createElement('custom-element')
const root = host.createShadowRoot()

document.body.appendChild(template)
document.body.appendChild(host)
root.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true))
```

This works, I can test my app's internal function calls by loggings, but nothing appears in dom. My app is made in ReactJS, thus i am able to log `ComponentDidMount` but cant see app in dom!

**Note:** 
If I refresh the page after initial entry, then this exact process runs to mount, but extention load as expected. Only on first entry there is a issue!

Comment: What's `makeTemplate`?

Comment: Its a function to handle styling etc & return elements

Comment: So it returns a DOM node. But you do `appendChild(template)` and then `importNode(template.content, true)`. Does it return an object with a `content` property or not?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I logs a `<template>` element with `document-fragment`. And this exact proccess runs when I refresh the page.

Comment: `<template>` elements by default have `display: none;`.

Comment: @connexo `display:none` is not a problem, cause I can't see that element in dom.

Comment: @Supersharp, I missed to put that line, question updated

Comment: @demonofthemist you should not use `createShadowRoot()` but instead `attachShadow( {mode:'open'} )`